# How to compare multiple columns in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

With MySQL, I can write SQL like below.

`select * from t where (col1,col2) < (?,?)`

How could I do this in Oracle?
`select * from t where (col1 < ?) or (col1=? and col2 < ?)` is not good enough.
It's not elegant, and will be hard to scale to N columns comparison.

Comment: I don't think you can. But I'm willing to be proved wrong...

Comment: For us Oracle dimwits, what does `(col1, col2) < (?, ?)` mean? If your suggested replacement is correct, it seems to mean `col1 <= first ?` and `col2 <= second ?` and at least one inequality is strict. Is that what you need? If so, either write your own little function, or write it as `col1 <= val1 and ... and colN <= valN and (col1+ ...+ colN) < (val1 + ... + valN)` (Actually that's how you should do it in a function, too, if you decided to go that way.) How often do you need such comparisons, though, anyway? What for?

Comment: @mathguy  I want to get all rows which is **smaller** than a given row. **smaller** is defined as rowA's `unique_key` is smaller than rowB's `unique_key`. And `unique_key` would be a union key.

Comment: Define smaller. Specifically, what do you mean by a ROW is smaller than another ROW? If you think that is a standard concept, just point to a definition somewhere.

Comment: @mathguy   smaller is defined as rowA's unique_key is smaller than rowB's unique_key. And unique_key would be a union key like (col1,col2,col3).

Comment: @mathguy Simply, I want to get rows which has a smaller index than a given row.

Comment: @mathguy The index we used to do the comparison is dynamically assigned by user.